# Align bar and line plot on x axis without the use of rank and pointplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Please note, I've looked at other questions like [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402358/seaborn-lineplot-and-barplot-dont-align-in-the-x-axis) and my problem is different and not a duplicate!

I would like to have two plots, with the same x axis in matplotlib. I thought this should be achieved via `constrained_layout`, but apparently this is not the case. Here is an example code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd

x = np.arange(0, 30, 0.001)
df_line = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": np.sin(x)})

df_bar = pd.DataFrame({
    "x_bar": [1, 7, 10, 20, 30], 
    "y_bar": [0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]
})

fig = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
gs = grd.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[3, 2], wspace=0.1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
sns.lineplot(data=df_line, x=df_line["x"], y=df_line["y"], ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("time", fontsize="22")
ax1.set_ylabel("y values", fontsize="22")
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
plt.setp(ax1.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize="22")
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
sns.barplot(data=df_bar, x="x_bar", y="y_bar", ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("time", fontsize="22")
ax2.set_ylabel("y values", fontsize="22")
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
```

this leads to the following figure.
[image: fig 1]

However, I would like to see the corresponding x values of both plot aligned. How can I achieve this? Note, I've tried to use the following related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402358/seaborn-lineplot-and-barplot-dont-align-in-the-x-axis). However, this doesn't fully apply to my situation. First with the high number of x points (which I need in reality) point plots is make the picture to big and slow for loading. On top, I can't use the rank method as my categories for the barplot are not evenly distributed. They are specific points on the x axis which should be aligned with the corresponding point on the lineplot

Comment: I am not sure that seaborn can do this. The bars are put on a linear scale (0,1,2,3,4 in this case) and the displayed values are just labels. I guess you should plot yourself the bars with the x you want.

Comment: How about plotting ``axvline`` instead of using bar plot? This way you can adjust the x axis the way you want and not linear like bar plot.

Comment: If you create a scale with equal intervals up to 30 and give it a label for the x-axis of the second graph, you will get something close to what you want. Is this the answer? `ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1,30,7));ax1.set_xticklabels(df_bar.x_bar.tolist())`

Comment: @Karina happy to use axvline. Can you show me how this would work for the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = np.arange(0, 30, 0.001)
df_line = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": np.sin(x)})

df_bar = pd.DataFrame({
    "x_bar": [1, 7, 10, 20, 30], 
    "y_bar": [0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]
})

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.plot(df_line['x'], df_line['y'])
for i in range(len(df_bar['x_bar'])):
    ax2.axvline(x=df_bar['x_bar'][i], ymin=0, ymax=df_bar['y_bar'][i])
```

Output:

[image]

---edit---

I incorporated @mozway advice for linewidth:

```
lw = (300/ax1.get_xlim()[1])
ax2.axvline(x=df_bar['x_bar'][i], ymin=0, ymax=df_bar['y_bar'][i], solid_capstyle='butt', lw=lw)
```

Output:

[image]

or:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! the only point which I would like to fix is that the axis (x-axis) are alinged. Is this doable?

Comment: Add `sharex=True` to `subplots`

Comment: Or `ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())` if you want both to have xticks

Comment: @Karina in `axvline` try to set `solid_capstyle='butt', lw=10` (test which lw value is best)

Comment: as mozway said, ``sharex=True`` omit the xticklabels from ``ax1``. but instead of ``lw=10`` I prefer ``lw = (300/ax1.get_xlim()[1])``, 300 is arbitrary. The problem with hard code ``lw=10`` is when the data get bigger, the line would still be ``lw=10``, which then hard to see

Comment: @swissy refer to my edit. The linewidth is now thicker and the x-axis are aligned.